# How to specify accessToken for Mapbox with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, access-token, mapbox

From Mapbox site I tested this code and success:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title></title>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.cs
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  .map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map' class='map'> </div>
<script>
var map = new L.Map('map', {
  center: new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.09),
  zoom: 8,
  layers: new L.TileLayer('https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.world-bright/{z}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I access my own map with markers and features? I suppose the "mapbox.world-bright" would be replaced by my own map.id, but how can I set the accessToken?

For some reasons I need to stick with Leaflet, and don't want to switch to mapbox.js.

Comment: PS. Don't forget to hide your access token, by, for example, using `process.env.YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` defined in `.env` file :) Of course, the `.env` file shouldn't be pushed to the Git repo!

Answer (score 3):

It's just a matter of using the right url in `L.TileLayer`. You'll need to add your mapId and token and use the correct attribution. It's also much better if you load the tiles from multiple subdomains because your browser can handle up to four connection as once. Code example:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{mapId}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={token}', {
    attribution: '<a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">&copy; Mapbox &copy; OpenStreetMap</a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c','d'],
    mapId: 'myMapId',
    token: 'myUserToken'
});
```

To add the features of your map you'll need to query those in a separate request. Here's an example using jQuery. You'll need to swap the MAPID and TOKEN for your mapid and token ofcourse:

```
$.getJSON('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/MAPID/features.json?access_token=TOKEN', function (data) {
      // Assuming the variable map contains your mapinstance
      var geojson = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
      map.fitBounds(geojson.getBounds());
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/h8F3kC?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I tried and indeed get the map style as in my project, but the markers and other features (e.g. polygons) were still missing :-(

Comment: Ok, understood, i read over the features part, i'll update my answer

Comment: It take some time for me to test, a bit progress but not I hit into CORS problem - browser just don't let me pass the 'getJSON' line...